# Getting sequence from SQL INSERT with JDBC

Tags: java, sql, insert, sequence, h2

So I'm trying to add to database using `JDBC` from files. And now when `INSERTING` I need to get the `ID` before I insert and it would be better If the database would still use the `sequence`.

In folder `resources` I have a file called `insert_plant.sql` that contains this query:

```
INSERT INTO PLANTS (id, plantname, species)
  VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR sequence, ?, null);
```

And the table is generated with this:

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;

CREATE SEQUENCE sequence START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE PLANTS (
   id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   plantname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   species VARCHAR(255) NULL,
);
```

And now in Java I am calling this:

```
public static void insertIntoOrderTable(BasicDataSource basicDataSource, String plantname) throws  SQLException{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        conn = basicDataSource.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Util.readFileFromClasspath("insert_plant.sql"));
        stmt.setString(1, plantname);
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        //Below is the line 57 (in error)
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT sequence.NEXTVAL FROM PLANTS");
        if(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("ID" + rs.getInt(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I get:

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: feature not supported
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.notSupported(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
at database.PlantDao.insertIntoOrderTable(PlantDao.java:57)
at database.PlantDao.main(PlantDao.java:19)
```

So the question

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It's probably not the source of your problem but it's not a good idea to use reserved keywords for variable names, naming your sequence sequence in this case.

Comment: @StephaneM i just put it here to be more understandable

Comment: @Andrew I am using hsqldb

Comment: For H2, I think the sytax is `NEXTVAL('SequenceName')`.

Comment: You don't need to execute a second statement to retrieve the `id` value. Right after the first `stmt.executeUpdate()` you can get the generated keys using the method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys().

Comment: @TheImpaler how exactly can I get it.. I do not quite get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented by ´The Impaler` there is no need to execute a second statement, with JDBC you can use

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"id"});
```

And to get the value out of it:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getLong(1));
}
```

So your method would look something like this:

```
public static void insertIntoOrderTable(BasicDataSource basicDataSource, String plantname) throws  SQLException{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        conn = basicDataSource.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Util.readFileFromClasspath("insert_plant.sql"), new String[]{"id"});
        stmt.setString(1, plantname);
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getLong(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still does not work with MSSQL https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/656 :(